# ListView Bottom To Top

Tags: android, listview

How can I make my listview cycle as in when the user reaches the bottom it essentially just reloads the top values and makes it an endless cycle?

Answer (score 1):

My thought process for your adapter would be:

1. Override `getCount()` and return `MAX_INT`
2. For `getItem()`, return your item at `position % actualCount` (i.e. if you're using a List called `items` for the backing data, return `items.get(pos % items.size())`).
3. In `getView()`, make sure that you're always accessing data using `getItem()` rather than accessing the backing data directly (e.g. don't access `items.get(pos)`, as you'll have to again mod against the length of the list)

Comment: Definitely check the commented duplicate, looks like a great solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is just off of top of my head, but I think roughly what you could do is, similar to detecting end in infinite-scrolling, when you're at the bottom, append to your ArrayList to itself then call an update like notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter?